# is there a way to log exception for all @ExceptionHandler in one place

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have `@ControllerAdvice` with numerous `@ExceptionHandler` methods with their own logic. However, I do need a log an original Exception.
Is there a way to do it without adding explicit logging message to each `@ExceptionHandler` method?

Answer (score -1):

No. You should define other Exception class and do not define it in `@ControllerAdvice` .

then you can use this Exception  and put in log

```
       catch (DefinedException ex) {
            log.info("your log here");
            throw ex;
        }
```

Comment: it can be done in `@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)` but my question was about single point to log all intercepted exceptions